# Winforms child window disappears behind owner

Tags: winforms, .net-3.5

I have a winforms MDI app where a window that is a "child" of the MDI form pops up a dialog, like this:

```
  AddPartsForm partsForm = new AddPartsForm( );
  partsForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
  DialogResult result = partsForm.ShowDialog( this );
```

As you can see, I have attempted both to center the dialog within its parent, and to establish who the parent is.  This generally works.  The dialog itself is a form with a dropdown list from which to select something that fills a grid on the same form.  Occasionally, the loading of the grid takes up to ten seconds.

During the loading, I am careful not to move my mouse or click on anything.  Yet, every so often (but not always) when the grid loads, the dialog "disappears" behind the form that called it.  I can find it in the system tray, but I want this not to happen.  There must be a parent/child or owner/child convention that most everyone uses and I have missed, because I do not see this kind of behavior in most software that I use.

Comment: Assuming your grid is initialized during `Form.Load` (and not in the constructor for example), I can offer you to set `AddPartsForm.TopMost` to `true` until the grid finished initializing.

Comment: The grid is loaded in response to a selection from a LookUpEdit on the same form.  It never disappears until after the grid finishes loading.  I can set TopMost, but then I feel like I'm not being a good citizen of the desktop - now I can't slide another window, say Word, over my form.